# How to fetch string and return as choice of datatypes

Tags: c#, casting

In my function, I am fetching a string.

However, I want to use the same function to return either an int, a bool OR a string.  Say I have gotten a string through some other function:

```
    public object read(string whatstring, string returnhow="string") {

    object result = "a string gotten from another function";

    switch(returnhow){
        case "int":
            result = int.TryParse(result, out result); break;
            case "bool":
                if (result=="0" || result=="false" || result=="") { returnthis = false; } else { returnthis = true; }; break;
        default:
            result = result.ToString(); break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
string thisvar = read("300", "int");
//or
bool thisvar = read("true", "string");
```

I don't think this is right.  Can I fix it, or am I going the wrong direction?

I do get an error, I suppose because of the way I am calling the function - but you get the idea of what I want.  I want it to be returned as the `type` that I declare the return value.  Maybe I am going the wrong direction?

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it, exactly? Note that there's a [Boolean.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method you can use just like its integer equivalent.

Comment: @DanJ I get the error above.  I added my call, which may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example implementation:

```
public static T GetByType<T> (string input) {
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string)) { return (T) Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T)); }


    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Int32)) { 
        int output;

        if(int.TryParse(input, out output)) { return (T) Convert.ChangeType(output, typeof(T)); }
    }

    if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool)) {
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(input == "1", typeof(T));
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input");
}
```

Working example:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Calling with string:");
    object type = GetByType<string>("0");
    Console.WriteLine (type.GetType());

    Console.WriteLine ("Calling with boolean:");
    type = GetByType<bool>("0");
    Console.WriteLine (type.GetType());

    Console.WriteLine ("Calling with integer:");
    type = GetByType<int>("0");
    Console.WriteLine (type.GetType());

    Console.WriteLine ("Calling with DateTime:");
    type = GetByType<DateTime>("0");
    Console.WriteLine (type.GetType());
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is what worked for me.  For anyone following, my calling function went like this:  `string thisvar = read<string>("mystring");` OR `bool thisbool = read<bool>("true");` OR `int thisint=read<int>("6");`  In each case, I could use the same function to parse a string and get the appropriate returned datatype.  Thanks, Jeroen!

Comment: This is horrible code. Example, when using int.tryparse, if it is successful, why not `return (T)output`, rather than calling ChangeType on it. Not to mention you have to add an if statement for each supported type you want to change.

Comment: Yes, I agree your answer should be accepted as well. I was not aware of these built-in converters.

Answer (score 3):

Use this.

```
public T ChangeType<T>(object value) 
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    return converter != null && converter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType()) 
        ? (T) converter.ConvertFrom(value) : default(T);        
}
```

This works with strings as the source, but also supports any other source type. As long as there is a type converter for it, and it can be converted, it will be. Otherwise, you'll get the default value (i.e. null for strings, 0 for ints, DateTime.MinValue for dates, etc.).

Same code, as an extension method of Object:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static T ChangeType<T<(this object value) 
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            return converter != null && converter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType()) 
                ? (T) converter.ConvertFrom(value) : default(T);        
        }
    }
}
```

The added bonus of using the built-in type conversion from the BCL is that you can support any custom types you want, just by implementing a type converter for them. MSDN has an example of implementing this for the Point class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).

Also, refer to Scott Hanselman's introductory article to this concept [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx).

Comment: good solution!! but please change one small thing: cast from object to T is missing: (T) converter.ConvertFrom(value)

Comment: Wow, you are way above me here!  I presume if I want to call it something besides `T` I can just change all the T's to something else?  Or is `T` locked in as a required parameter value somewhere?

Comment: I had to add `using System.ComponentModel;` too, in case anyone is following this thread.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something else.  I get an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`  - Maybe *I'm* missing something!

Comment: Yes BGM, use `(T) converter.ConvertFrom(value)` as road242 noted. I forgot that ConvertFrom returns an  object, so you need to do the actual cast explicitly. I've updated the sample accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function similar to this:

```
    public object Convert(string toConvert, Type typeToConvert)
    {
        if(typeToConvert is string)
        {
            return toConvert;
        }
        else if(typeToConvert is bool)
        {
            bool convertedOutput;
            if (bool.TryParse(toConvert, out convertedOutput))
            {
                return convertedOutput;
            }
        }
        else if (typeToConvert is Int64 || typeToConvert is Int32 || typeToConvert is Int16)
        {
            Int64 convertedOutput;
            if (Int64.TryParse(toConvert, out convertedOutput))
            {
                return convertedOutput;
            }
        }
        // additional converts here...

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics might be the way to go for your requirement. There is a code snippet...

```
    public T read<T>(string whatstring, string returnhow = "string")
    {
        T result = default(T) ;
        // Do Something
        return result;
    }
```

Good Luck!

Comment: If we do that, then I don't need the second parameter of `returnhow`, right?

Comment: Maybe you forgot something in that function - but where does `whatstring` actually get its type changed?

Comment: how does this do anything different than returning a default value?

Comment: Nah, I figured him out.  It works like this:  `bool mybool = read<bool>("false"); Console.WriteLine(testme);`  Very concise, actually.  +1